# ALT + SELECT in edit mode selects whole mesh instead of edge loop

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges

I have a grid which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, when i try to use ALT + SELECT in order to select one edge loop, it instead selects the whole mesh.

How can i  fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops can't be selected with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd> without faces. You can select all <kbd>A</kbd>, and make faces with <kbd>F</kbd>, then you'll be able to select loops.